# Can convert date to long but long is too big?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm very confused right now.

I have a `GregorianCalendar` object which I give a specific date (Jan 1st 2010).

**Calendar:**

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.set(2010, 0, 1);
System.out.println(c.getTime());
System.out.println(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

**Output:**

> Fri Jan 01 13:12:57 CET 2010
>
> 1262347977927

Now when I try to create a `long` and store this number in it, the number is actually too big for my variable.

**Storing in variable:**

```
long timeStamp = 1262347977927;
// ERROR: The literal 1262347977927 of type int is out of range
```

But when I store the result directly into my variable, it works just fine.

**Directly storing:**

```
long timeStamp = c.getTimeInMillis();
System.out.println(timeStamp);
```

**Output:**

> 1262348451631

Why is the long that I get too big to be a long, yet not too long to be a long? I'm confused.

I'm using Java 6 and Eclipse Indigo if anyone would want to know.

**EDIT: Thanks for all the instant answers... I feel really stupid now :p**

Comment: don't feel stupid! ask yourself why those answers came like shot from a minigun: every programmer has to face this problem by time :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have to add a **L** after the literal:

```
long timeStamp = 1262347977927L;
```

Answer (score 6):

Always refer to the docs, [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> An integer literal is of type **long** if it ends with the letter **L** or **l**;
>   otherwise it is of type **int**. It is recommended that you use the upper
>   case letter **L** because the lower case letter **l** is hard to distinguish
>   from the digit **1**.

Answer (score 5):

You must append an `L` or `l`

```
long timeStamp = 1262347977927L;
```

literal to the assigned value otherwise an integer value is assumed by the compiler

The former is preferable as the latter looks like a `1`!

Answer (score 5):

User the L at the end of the number:

```
long timeStamp = 1262347977927L;
```

It defines the Number as Long.

Answer (score 4):

No `1262347977927` is not big enough for a long number (which is 8 bytes).

Make it like this:

```
long timeStamp = 1262347977927L;
```

L for long declaration.

Reason is that in Java by default all numbers are treated as int type unless you put switches like `L` in the end.

Or simple:

```
long timeStamp = c.getTimeInMillis()
```

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
long timeStamp = 1262347977927;
```

to

```
long timeStamp = 1262347977927L;
```

Note that you need to suffix 'L' (preferred) or 'l' (suffixing this can lead to difficult to read code; there's a a [java puzzler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032133678X) entry related to this) at the end .

Answer (score 4):

It's not telling you that 1262347977927 can't fit into a long, it's telling you that it can't construct an int constant of value 1262347977927, before it even tries to assign it into the long variable. Notice how timeStamp is never mentioned in the error:

> The literal 1262347977927 of type int is out of range

Use L after the number to mark it as a long constant, then you can assign it without problems:

```
long timeStamp = 1262347977927L;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try appending 'L' after your number while assigning it to long variable.